# librav1e: error while loading shared library libc.so: invalid ELF header

Tags: linux, ld

I'm trying to use precompiled binaries of librav1e: https://github.com/xiph/rav1e/releases/tag/v0.6.6

More precisely, I'm using librav1e-0.6.6-linux-aarch64.tar.gz (also tried weekly build with the same result) on Ubuntu 18.04.

When I'm trying to compile another library which is depends on librav1e:

```
[ 84%] Linking CXX executable heif-test
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libc.so, needed by //usr/local/lib/librav1e.so.0, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/local/lib/librav1e.so.0: undefined reference to `fstat64'
/usr/local/lib/librav1e.so.0: undefined reference to `stat64'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Inspecting .so file:

```bash
# tar xvf librav1e-linux-aarch64.tar.gz 
include/
include/rav1e/
include/rav1e/rav1e.h
lib/
lib/librav1e.a
lib/librav1e.so
lib/librav1e.so.0.6.1
lib/librav1e.so.0
lib/pkgconfig/
lib/pkgconfig/rav1e.pc

# ldd ./lib/librav1e.so
./lib/librav1e.so: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so: invalid ELF header

# dpkg -S libc.so
libc6-dev:arm64: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so
libc6:arm64: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

# cat /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so
/* GNU ld script
   Use the shared library, but some functions are only in
   the static library, so try that secondarily.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-littleaarch64)
GROUP ( /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a  AS_NEEDED ( /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 ) )

# rm /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so
# ldd ./lib/librav1e.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000ffff95b61000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000ffff9590d000)
    libc.so => not found
    libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000ffff957b4000)
    /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x0000ffff95b35000)
```

So it looks like there two shared versions of `libc.so` in `librav1e.so` and one of them is GNU ld script in my system. Is this ok? What can I do with errors?

Comment: upgrade libc.so.6

Comment: Please don't suggest that people upgrade libc on an OS, because that's a great way to break pretty much the entire OS.  If a newer version of libc is needed, one should upgrade the OS itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package you're using is not correctly linked.  On Linux, every shared library installed for public use has an SONAME, which specifies the shared library path.  This value should contain the unqualified name, which should be in the form `libfoo.so.N`, where *foo* is the shared library name, and *N* is the ABI version.  Different values of *N* result in incompatible libraries.

It isn't acceptable to link libraries directly against a name such as `libc.so`, since that doesn't contain an ABI version.  Now, it is extremely unlikely that glibc will change its ABI version, but in the past, there were different versions of libc, and you would not want to link a program using glibc 2 (`libc.so.6`) with a program using libc5 (`libc.so.5`).  Libraries that are correctly compiled for public use will not link against libc in this way.

You should not delete `/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so` (and you should re-install the package providing it if you have), and either compile the shared library yourself or report the problem to the maintainer.

Note that newer versions of Debian and Ubuntu ship this package, so you may find that it's helpful to download that source package and build it, modifying as necessary, which will build it in a way that works with your OS.  That may, however, be made more difficult by the fact that Ubuntu 18.04 is no longer receiving regular updates, security or otherwise.

Comment: Maintainer says that that versions are compiled against musl instead of glibc. It's not required, but if you know, why musl is linked that way?

Comment: Probably because it's designed to be statically linked.  In any event, you cannot use a distribution dynamically linked against musl if you want to run on Debian or Ubuntu, which use glibc.